# Change One Word Of PHP File Using PHP Script

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with an entry textbox that is identified as `username`.
When the submit button is pressed this code is used:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$myUser=$_POST['username'];  
$path="/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/userfiles/";
$fpath="/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/userfiles/user.php";
$myFolder = $path . $myUser;
$myFile = $myUser.".php";
$old_umask = umask(0);
mkdir($myFolder, 0777);
$myFileDes = $myFolder."/".$myFile;
copy($fpath, $myFileDes);  
umask($old_mask);
}
?>
```

This creates a directory and a file, the file is duplicated from user.php In user.php there is this code that needs to be changed upon submit:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='will';");
```

It needs to change where it says `username='will';`
It needs to change will to the username defined in the form.

How would I do this?

Comment: This could help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: you can probably do a fopen and buffer the content into php and then search for that query statement, do the modification, and then write it out into it and replace the previous content with the edited content.

Comment: This sounds like a possibly bad idea architecurally. It would probably be more feasible to store the database credentials in a file separate from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the username dynamically from the directory the file is inside. Use `dirname` and `__FILE__` to get:

```
$username = dirname(__FILE__);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='" . $username . "';");
```

Also i would advise you to filter the input from the user:

```
$myUser = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $myUser);
```

This would replace every character that is no alphanumerical character or an underscore by an empty string. Otherwise the user can select `"../../../foo/"` as username which would probably break the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the original user.php content first, then replace the string with value you want.

```
$content = "";              // read Text file, read all lines into an array
if ($arr = @file ($fpath))      // Do this if file exists
    foreach ($arr as $line) $content .= $line.'\n';

$fp = fopen ($myFileDes, "w");  // create new file
$newContent = str_replace("'will'", $myUser, $content);
fputs ($fp, $newContent);
fclose ($fp);
```